# Issue with TableviewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

[image]

I have 2 sections both with 3 rows. Basically I want the section 0, row 0 to only have the image and label combo. all the other rows will only be containing text. It has a logout on the footer. how do I go about removing the repetitiveness, I know it's because im using the dequereuseable cell but I can't find a work around.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato", size: 20.0)
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.05
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.userFirstName.text = userFirstName
      
        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare 2 different cells with 2 different layouts and different identifiers. Then dequeue proper one based on `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` values.